# Проблема с редактированием xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Проблема такая, работаю в   пхп скрипте с xml файлом, все подгружается без вопросов, информацию из файла считывает корректно, но не сохраняет изменения в файле, при том ошибок никаких не вижу, программа отрабатывает корректно, а в xml ничего не меняется. Возможно что-то с правами на запись,но is_writible($filename) === true

часть кода

```
if (file_exists('database.xml')) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('database.xml');

} else {
    exit('Не удалось открыть файл database.xml');
}


$users = $xml->xpath("//users/user/login[. = '{$login}']");
if(count($users) > 0) { // if found
    echo json_encode("not unique login");
    exit();
}
$users = $xml->xpath("//users/user/email[. = '{$email}']");
if(count($users) > 0) { // if found
    echo json_encode("not unique email");
    exit();
}
//генерируем динамическую соль из даты и шифр пароль
$datenow = date('YmdHis');//извлекаем    дату
$soul = md5($datenow);// шифруем    дату
$md5password= md5($password.$soul);


$addUsers= $xml->users->addChild("user");


$addUser->addChild('name', $name);
$addUser->addChild('login', $login);
$addUser->addChild('password', $md5password);
$addUser->addChild('email', $email);
```

мой xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<users>

    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <user>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>test</name>
        <login>user123</login>
        <password>user123</password>
        <email>user123@mail.ru</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: `$soul` это у вас _соль_ типа? :)

Comment: где запись в файл то обратно? не ожидаете ведь вы, что оно само по себе запишется?

Comment: @teran Может подскажите как это должно выглядеть? добавил строчку $xml->asXML('database.xml');  , работать лучше не стало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите отображение варнингов пхп, это поможет избежать многих ошибок.

Во-первых, при добавлении не надо указывать корневой узел. Вместо

```
$addUsers= $xml->users->addChild("user");
```

надо просто написать

```
$addUsers = $xml->addChild("user");
```

а во-вторых, исправьте в данной же строке имя переменной на `$addUser` без `s` на конце, как в вашем дальнейшем коде.

В третьих, как уже написали в комментариях, изменения надо сохранить.

```
$xml->saveXML('filename.xml'); //->asXML - то же самое
```

Также добавлю, что `quantity` лучше сделать атрибутом `users`, а не узлом.